# Azure OpenAI Studio: Error Message "We couldn't connect your data" when using "Add your data"

Tags: azure-openai

I'm getting the followig message: "We couldn't connect your data" using Azure OpenAI Studio.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muz9c.png)

I already used on the past with no issues, but now i'm facing this issue.

Best Regards,
Bruno Gil

Diferent upload options same behavior